# Add res/raw folder content file (video) to external SD folder

Tags: android

The idea is I want to put the content/s of my res/raw folder to external sd folder named "myFolder".

my way is that I used Uri to access the video file in res/raw and used FileOutputStream and its not working, Is my way possible?

*I already have the permissions needed to READ and WRITE to external sd, and it is placed correclty in manifest.

CODE IS BELOW, THANK YOU

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    String basepath = extStorageDirectory + "/myFolder/";
    Uri UriPath=Uri.parse
            ("android.resource://com.example.videoplayer.videoplayer/" + R.raw.video1); 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplayer);

    File videodir= new File(basepath);
    if (!videodir.exists()) {
        videodir.mkdirs();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Directory created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Directory exists!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    File file = new File (basepath, "android.resource://com.example.videoplayer.videoplayer/" + R.raw.video1); //Im not sure if the code reaches the video1 file

    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); //this line doesnt work
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "File created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "File error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error? Or are you looking for sample codes on how to do it?

Comment: the application runs and it executes the "File error!" toast.
I just want a working code (edit on my code) to add the res/raw files to external sd folder to be discussed in this post.Thank you for replying

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void copyFileOrDir(String path) {
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
String assets[] = null;
try {
    assets = assetManager.list(path);
    if (assets.length == 0) {
        copyFile(path);
    } else {
        String fullPath = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + path;
        File dir = new File(fullPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();
        for (int i = 0; i < assets.length; ++i) {
            copyFileOrDir(path + "/" + assets[i]);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Log.e("tag", "I/O Exception", ex);
 }
}

private void copyFile(String filename) {
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();

InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    in = assetManager.open(filename);
    String newFileName = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + filename;
    out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    in = null;
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    out = null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
}

}
```

To use above code call function with copyFileOrDir("myFolder");

Comment: Thank you kishan! you're a great help.